# Moving the workload from PHP to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have two queries that are executed in order. The first query pulls a few rows from a database and the 2nd query is executed using one value from those rows. I am only interested in the rows from the 1st query where I know the 2nd query is going to return a value higher than 0. I could potentially have thousands of rows in my first table, so I rather do the filtering in MySQL and not in PHP, I would assume it is faster.

The first query is as following

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    wp_invoices 
WHERE 
    deleted = 0
```

The 2nd query is as following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_users A
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta B ON (A.ID = B.user_id)  
    LEFT JOIN wp_invoices_records C ON (A.ID = C.uid 
        AND C.invoice_id = %d 
        AND C.status != 100) 
WHERE (B.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND CAST(B.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%%\"subscriber\"%%') 
    AND (C.uid IS NOT NULL)
```

Both queries work separately, this is not the problem. Currently, the `%d` in the 2nd query is replaced by PHP, which inserts the `wp_invoices.id` value for each row.

Ideally, I would like a query that returns only the rows from wp_invoices, where the 2nd query would return a value higher than 0. At this point I am not interested in the rows of the 2nd query, only the amount of rows found.

My table structures are as following: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/466cb

This is what I do in PHP, currently, to handle all this. Please keep in mind that this code was written to clarify this post, I am using deprecated MySQL functions because I don't write PHP that often anymore and haven't really looked into mysqli and I haven't checked if this code actually runs. It should give you a better indication of what I am currently doing.

```php
<?php

    /* Example code. I am not using mysql_ functions in my own solution, I just 
       know these functions by heart. Assume a database connection is already 
       established */

    /* Refer to this as QUERY 1 */
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_invoices WHERE deleted = 0");

    /* Loop over all invoices (this is not an invoice 'record'. These are 
       the invoice definitions, not the actual instances that people received */
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        /* Refer to this as QUERY 2 */
        $count_result = mysql_query(sprintf("
            SELECT 
                COUNT(*) AS count
            FROM wp_users A 
            INNER JOIN wp_usermeta B ON (A.ID = B.user_id)  
            LEFT JOIN wp_invoices_records C ON (A.ID = C.uid 
                AND C.invoice_id = %d 
                AND C.status != 100) 
            WHERE (B.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
                AND CAST(B.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%%\"subscriber\"%%') 
                AND (C.uid IS NOT NULL)", $row['id']));

        if(mysql_result($count_result, 0) > 0) {

            /* Here I would pull all data I would need for this invoice. $row
               contains all the information about the invoice, $invoice_record
               will contain all the information for this particular user about
               this invoice*/
            $invoice_records = mysql_query(sprintf("
                SELECT
                    A.ID AS id,
                    A.display_name,
                    C.id AS received,
                    DATE_FORMAT(C.received_on, '%%d-%%m-%%Y') AS received_on,
                    C.status,
                    A.user_email,
                    C.price,
                    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' 
                        AND user_id = A.ID) AS first_name,
                    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'tssnvgsl' 
                        AND user_id = A.ID) AS insertion,
                    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'last_name' 
                        AND user_id = A.ID) AS last_name
                FROM wp_users A
                INNER JOIN wp_usermeta B ON (A.ID = B.user_id)  
                LEFT JOIN wp_invoices_records C ON (A.ID = C.uid 
                    AND C.invoice_id = %d 
                    AND C.status != 100) 
                WHERE (B.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
                    AND CAST(B.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%%\"subscriber\"%%') 
                    AND (C.uid IS NOT NULL)", $row['id']));

            while($invoice_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($invoice_records)) {
                /* Perform logic to see if this person should receive a reminder */
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

What I attempt to achieve, though:

```
<?php

        $result = mysql_query(/* here a query that pulls all rows from QUERY 1
                where QUERY 2 would have returned a count higher than 2 */);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                /* Now here I should be 100% sure that every $row has at least one
                   "pending" invoice record, that has not yet been paid and has a
                   status of < 100 */
        }

?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking to accomplish independent from your existing process? What is the business logic for the scenario?

Comment: @nullReference I am writing a invoicing system that allows the user to send invoices by pressing one button. Personal information is inserted into the template and sent via email. People that haven't paid should receive reminders after x amount of days, and I only want my cronjob to handle invoices that have more than 1 'unpaid' invoice. Currently, I loop over all invoices to see if there are any invoices of that type which are currently not paid yet. I could narrow it down to only pull the invoices that have more than 1 not paid invoice by doing this using MySQL instead of PHP

Comment: @nullReference to make it more clear, an "invoice" can be made and sent to multiple people. So there's an "invoice record" (which is an instance of the previously generated invoice). Invoice records can be either active (not paid yet) or non-active (paid). The paid ones don't require attention, thus don't need to be included in the cronjob. If a particular invoice has 0 active records, it doesn't have to be included within the cronjob.

Comment: @nullReference Yes. Status 100 means it has been paid, status 0 means it was just sent, 1 means 1st reminder, 2 means 2nd reminder, and so on. I'm interested in all records that have a status that is not 100 or less than 100.

Comment: @RubenRutten please inline your code samples instead of hosting them on pastebin. External code links on pastebin tend to die after a while

Comment: @JoshJ Done that now

Comment: @Oldskool This only tells me you haven't read my comments in the code

Comment: @RubenRutten You are right, I jumped to conclusions too quickly. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I have been racking my brain staring at your process and I think it is starting to make sense. If I am not mistaken you should be able to eliminate both query1 and query2 and move the logic into the LEFT JOIN of your third query like such.

```
SELECT
   A.ID AS id,
   A.display_name,
   C.id AS received,
   DATE_FORMAT(C.received_on, '%%d-%%m-%%Y') AS received_on,
   C.status,
   A.user_email,
   C.price,
   (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' 
           AND user_id = A.ID) AS first_name,
   (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'tssnvgsl' 
           AND user_id = A.ID) AS insertion,
   (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'last_name' 
           AND user_id = A.ID) AS last_name
FROM wp_users A
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta B ON (A.ID = B.user_id)  
LEFT JOIN wp_invoices_records C ON (A.ID = C.uid 
   AND C.invoice_id IN (SELECT id FROM wp_invoices WHERE deleted = 0)
   AND C.status != 100) 
WHERE (B.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
   AND CAST(B.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%%\"subscriber\"%%') 
   AND (C.uid IS NOT NULL)"
```

This query, instead of having to be ran every time for every record and the $row['id'] added via php within your LEFT JOIN I am using MySQL IN functionality with a subselect. This gives you the ability to join only on records from wp_invoices which where deleted.

Comment: I have tried your query but it doesn't produce the results I need. I updated my original answer with PHP code that shows what I am currently doing. I find it very hard to express what I need.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to provide me with the correct information. I either want just the columns from `wp_invoices` where the 2nd query (`COUNT(*)` would've been `> 0`), or I would like the records the way you just provided them, and the added columns from `wp_invoices`. The query you gave me right gives me exactly the same output as my 2nd query with the `%d` manually substituted with a number. I'll provide example data tomorrow.